# Django raising DatabaseError running a Model.objects.get

Tags: django, django-models, postgresql-9.1, tastypie

I am using Django 1.4, postgres 9.1.x, and Tastypie 0.9.11 to create an API.

I have defined the following model:

```
class Activity(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company)
    opportunity = models.ForeignKey(Opportunity)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    ...
```

I am overwriting the "save" method to do some special stuff during this process:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    saveResult = None
    try: 
        saveResult = super(Activity, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    except IntegrityError, e:
        logger.error('IntegrityError %s' % e.message)

    if(not self.pk):
        try:
            self = Activity.objects.get(company_id=self.company.id,opportunity_id=self.opportunity.id)
        except ObjectDoesNotExist, e:
            pass
        except DatabaseError, e:
            logger.error('DatabaseError %s' % e.message)

    if(self.pk and not self.notified):
        send_notification(...)
        self.notified = 1
        self.save()

    return saveResult
```

Below I describe an example of the POST requests that I'm doing:

```
curl --dump-header - -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"company": {"id":10},"opportunity": {"id":39}}'  http://127.0.0.1:8001/api/v1/activity/
```

The process is working well for new objects, but when I do a POST request for an existing row (I don't have a way to know previously if it is new or not), I'm getting of course the IntegrityError due to the duplicate key error, which is correct.

Then, I want to populate the self data with the info stored in the existing row, that's why I do the following query (I didn't find a more elegant way to do it, if you have a better option would be appreciated):

> self =
>   Activity.objects.get(company_id=self.company.id,opportunity_id=self.opportunity.id)

The problem is that the process is dying because that "get" line is throwing a DatabaseError with message "current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block" avoiding to obtain the existing object.

These are the messages I am getting printed in screen:

```
2012-10-18T04:57:27+00:00 app[web.1]: .............Saving new activity.............
2012-10-18T04:57:27+00:00 app[web.1]: Company: 10, video test | Opportunity: 39 | Activity: , created: None, None, 1, 
2012-10-18T04:57:27+00:00 app[web.1]: IntegrityError duplicate key value violates unique constraint "db_activity_company_id_1276b66f55cae366_uniq"
2012-10-18T04:57:27+00:00 app[web.1]: DETAIL:  Key (company_id, opportunity_id)=(10, 39) already exists.
2012-10-18T04:57:27+00:00 app[web.1]: DatabaseError current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
```

BTW: I have tried exactly the same in MySql and it works well.

So, I don't know why is the "get" method generating the error. I guess it may be related with the previous IntegrateError raised, but I haven't figure out how to avoid it.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand the logic here. Looking at your code at this line

```
 if(not self.pk):
    try:
        self = Activity.objects.get(company_id=self.company.id,opportunity_id=self.opportunity.id)
    except ObjectDoesNotExist, e:
        pass
    except DatabaseError, e:
        logger.error('DatabaseError %s' % e.message)
```

You are saying: if the current object (self) does not exist in the database. Take an existing one and assign to it. That is not how self is working.

You should first check if the record exists in the DB. If it exists assign it to a local variable. If it doesn't exist, save it and then add it to the same local variable.

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):

    try:
        saveResult = Activity.objects.get(company_id=self.company.id,opportunity_id=self.opportunity.id)
    except ObjectDoesNotExist, e:
        #Object does not exist. Add it
        saveResult = super(Activity, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    if not saveResult.notified:
        send_notification(...)
        saveResult.notified = 1
        saveResult.save()

    return saveResult
```

Comment: "You are saying: if the current object (self) does not exist in the database. Take an existing one and assign to it. That is not how self is working."...The thing is that when I'm receiving the data, it does not include any pk yet but the composed key with foreign key relations. So yes, what I need to do is to check if it already exists, if not, to create it...and I thought the logic trying to insert, and if fails, then read...however I think your solution makes  sense...I messed up trying to continue using the "self". Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Catching DB Errors and then continue if nothing has happened looks strange to me.

```
current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
```

You need to use savepoints, if you want to continue after an error like this in postgres.

Maybe `Activity.objects.get_or_create(..., defaults=dict(attr=value))` does all you need.

Comment: Thank you for your answer...the get_or_create method generates an infinite loop due to the fact that it's been called into the "save" method.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to manage the transaction yourself ? (see below for an example)
It looks like the whole save method is wrapped within a single transaction so that the first query after a query which raised an error will always raise an exception.

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    with transaction.commit_manually:
        saveResult = None
        sid = transaction.savepoint()
        try: 
            saveResult = super(Activity, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
            transaction.savepoint_commit(sid)
        except IntegrityError, e:
            logger.error('IntegrityError %s' % e.message)
            transaction.savepoint_rollback(sid)
        transaction.commit()

    if(not self.pk):
        try:
            self = Activity.objects.get(company_id=self.company.id,opportunity_id=self.opportunity.id)
        except ObjectDoesNotExist, e:
            pass
        except DatabaseError, e:
            logger.error('DatabaseError %s' % e.message)

    if(self.pk and not self.notified):
        send_notification(...)
        self.notified = 1
        self.save()

    return saveResult
```